# Download CSV file with todays date from Outlook inbox and save it to a folder using powershell. My code doesnt seem to be working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, csv, attachments

I am trying to write a powershell script to download a csv emailed daily save it to a folder, and then process it using powershell/excel.  I have already written the powershell to open up the file and process it using a excel macro written in VBA, but I cannot seem to get this code below to download the attachment.   The file name that is emailed is typically exceptions_123456.csv but filenames sometimes change, but its always .CSV and is the only csv file I get daily.  so I want to download any csv file emailed to me on todays date sent to my inbox.
this is the code I have tried, it doesnt seem to work.  I do not get any errors, I even tried replacing the $today variable with today's date manually "03/23/2023" and it wont download either.  not sure where the issue is.

```
    Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olDefaultFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$FilePath= "c:\exceptions\"
$today = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$subfolder.Items | Where-Object {$_.receivedtime -match $today -and $($_.attachments).filename -match '.csv'} | foreach {
    foreach($attachment in $($_.attachments | where filename -match '.csv'))
    {
        Write-Host Downloading $attachment.filename to $filepath -ForegroundColor green
        $attachment.SaveAsFile((join-path $FilePath $attachment.filename))
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with referencing the attachment and the `$subfolder.Items` not being accessible. Note - make sure outlook app is closed. Try this:

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olDefaultFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
$inbox = $mapi.getDefaultFolder($olDefaultFolders::olFolderInBox)
$FilePath= "c:\exceptions\"
$today = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"

$inboxitems = $inbox.Items | Where-Object {$_.receivedtime -ge $today -and $($_.attachments).filename -match '.csv'} 
foreach ($inboxitem in $inboxitems) { 
$name = $inboxitem.Attachments | Select Filename
Write-Host Downloading $name to $filepath -ForegroundColor green
        $($inboxitem.Attachments).SaveAsFile((join-path $FilePath $name.FileName))
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will test this out  and see if it works, although not having outlook open may be a problem in general.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately it is a requirement of using the interop

Comment: Tested this out, but still not working, although it seemed to be doing something, but it ran way too long.  powershell just hung up.  but my inbox is very large.  so going to try and rework this to download from a inbox subfolder with much less emails.  Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Are your email accounts Office365 by chance? If so, there are some nice libraries that can rip attachments right from the exchange 365 webserver using graph api